# Incorrect URL to file in Django admin

Tags: django

I'm getting the wrong URL to files that have been uploaded to the media-folder in the Django admin.

The URL for the file is:

```
/media/Users/hammer/Dev/*****/media/attachments/2018/09/12/pdf-test.pdf
```

But the correct URL to the file is:

```
/media/attachments/2018/09/12/pdf-test.pdf
```

It seems like MEDIA_ROOT (/Users/hammer/Dev/*****/media/) is (incorrectly, I guess) added after the first /media/ in the URL.

MEDIA_URL is:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

MEDIA_ROOT is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = settings.BASE_DIR + '/media/'
```

The definition of the file-field for the model is:

```
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "attachments/%Y/%m/%d/", null=True)
```

The incorrect URL for the file-field is appearing on the change-page for the model for the file field.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: No, no ideas, because you didn't provide any details. What is MEDIA_URL set to? What is the definition for that field in the model, especially the `upload_to` parameter? Where are you seeing this incorrect URL and what code is displaying it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've provided the details you asked for in the question now.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include MEDIA_ROOT specifically in your upload_to parameter. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> If you are using the default FileSystemStorage, the string value will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT path to form the location on the local filesystem where uploaded files will be stored.

So, just remove that:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to="attachments/%Y/%m/%d/", null=True)
```

You'll need to recreate the instances with the incorrect value in the db, though.

Comment: Also if they already have stored absolute paths in the DB, then they should make sure they remove the prefix ``/media/Users/hammer/Dev/*****/media/`` from existing data to leave only the relative path starting from upload_to.

Comment: @jpic There are absolute paths stored in the DB so I have to fix that.

Comment: Django filepath should have the relative path without MEDIA_ROOT in the db.